Object belongs to class and has property in typescript?
import type { Scene, Camera } from 'three'

interface SceneWithActiveCamera extends Scene {
  activeCamera: Camera
}

let scene: SceneWithActiveCamera

Is there a simpler way to do this? For example, without an interface?

That's... pretty simple already. Do you consider an intersection like this "simpler"?  Are you only using your new type once or lots of times?

(See prev comment) Please [edit] the question to clarify what you mean by "simpler". Apparently it's subjective and therefore this will solicit opinions instead of objective answers. Or maybe you just want to say "is there another way to do this" instead of mentioning simplicity?

You can use intersection of types. See details on Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces
  type SceneWithActiveCamera = Scene & {activeCamera: Camera};


By what criterion is this "simpler" than the interface? Number of keystrokes?

It's definitely a way without interface, someone might consider it simpler.

If simplicity is subjective then we should get OP to edit and clarify what they mean and make it more objective. Right now I can't tell whether the correct answer here is "yes, use an intersection", or "no, there's nothing simpler than interface extension, which is one of the most basic functionalities in TypeScript"
